# WCF: Interfaces, Generics and ServiceKnownType

Tags: .net, wcf, generics, interface, serviceknowntype

I have the following:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(ActionParameters))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(SportProgram))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(ActionResult<SportProgram>))]
public interface ISportProgramBl  
{
    [OperationContract]
    IActionResult<ISportProgram> Get(IActionParameters parameters);
}
```

When I run the Get method I get the following error:

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:GetResult. The InnerException message was 'Type 'PPS.Core.DomainModel.Support.Action.ActionResult`1[ [PPS.Core.DomainModel.SportProgram.ISportProgram, PPS.Core.DomainModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' with data contract name 'ActionResultOfanyType: http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PPS.Core.DomainModel.Support.Action' is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

From this error I can see that it can resolve ActionResult but it can't resolve ISportProgram even though I have **ServiceKnownType(typeof(ActionResult < SportProgram >))** on my service interface...

Note this is the Reference stub that is generated looks like this, so I can see that the known types are being brought across correctly:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="SportProgramStb.ISportProgramBl")]
public interface ISportProgramBl {

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/ISportProgramBl/Get", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/ISportProgramBl/GetResponse")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(PPS.Core.DomainModel.SportProgram.SportProgram))]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(PPS.Core.DomainModel.Support.Action.ActionParameters))]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(PPS.Core.DomainModel.Support.Action.ActionResult<PPS.Core.DomainModel.SportProgram.SportProgram>))]
    object Get(object parameters);
}
```

Why is this going wrong???? Note its getting through the WCF service correctly... but it throws the exception when the result is returned.

Lastly ActionResult looks like this:

```
public interface IActionResult<T> 
{
    T Result { get; set; } 
}
```

Cheers
Anthony

Comment: The type `ActionResult<ISportProgram>` that `Serializer` expects is different from the type `ActionResult<SportProgram>` provided in `ServiceKnownType`!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, I think this is another case of the SOA vs. OOP "impedance mismatch". The two world are quite separate.

In WCF, all that is being passed from the client to the server is passed as **serialized messages** - no references are being used.

This means: everything you want to serialize on the client, send it across to the server, and deserialize it and use it there, must be **concrete** - you cannot pass around interfaces, you cannot use "non-resolved" generics - you need to spell it out. Basically, all that's being passed from client over the wire to the server must be expressable in XML schema.

This has lots of implications:

- no interfaces - you cannot pass around interfaces - you need to work with concrete types
- no "automatic" inheritance - you cannot just define a base class and pass around derived classes based on it - those need to be specificied too (that's what the ServiceKnownType attribute is for)
- no automatic generics - again, you need to use concrete types instead

This may sound like a lot of restrictions - but it's because WCF is using all message-based communication - it cannot deal with refereces, inheritance, generics etc. - you need to spell it out.

So I don't really have an answer for you per se - I just think you need to rethink your strategy and change the way your client and server are exchanging information over WCF.

Marc

PS: I did some more research, and contrary to all my understanding, there seems to be a way to serialize anything that's based on an interface and/or abstract base class across the wire, as long as you can be sure it's always only .NET on either end of the wire (i.e. it's **not** interoperable with e.g. Java).

See [Aaron Skonnard blog post on the NetDataContractSerializer](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/aaron/archive/2006/04/21/22284.aspx) and another [blog post](http://www.thoughtshapes.com/WCF/UsingInterfacesAsParametersTwo.htm) and [yet another](http://blogs.msdn.com/domgreen/archive/2009/04/13/wcf-using-interfaces-in-method-signatures.aspx) showing how to use the NetDataContractSerializer to be able to pass around things like `IPerson` as parameters to your methods.

Comment: I'm willing to give WCF all the hints it needs but I can not avoid using the interfaces or the generics... if somehow I can get rid of the interfaces can I still use generics?? also is the reverse true if i can get rid of the generics can I still use interfaces... meaning is it just the combinaton of the 2 that are causing me issues?? Because I could create more specific version of  IActionResult<ISportProgram> that doesn't require the generics to be used...

Comment: Updated my post with some new info I found while researching this matter - hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the problems that I solve with [ServiceStack.NET](http://www.servicestack.net) - My Open Source .NET and MONO Web Services Framework.

Service Stack was heavily influenced by [Martin Fowlers Data Transfer Object Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) as it allows you to simply use DTO's to define your web services - i.e. the SOA way :).

I avoid this limitation that's inherent in WCF by generating my own WSDL's that behave as you would expect them to. As a benefit of replacing WCF's complex configuration / ServiceContract's model - The SOAP web services also works on MONO - [see the live demo](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Examples.Clients/Soap12.aspx).

Comment: Looks interesting but the live demo link is a 404

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question and even though the accepted answer is totally correct, I stumpled upon this in the search for a similiar problem and thought I could share my experiences. It's often a headache, but it is possible to use generics combined with interfaces with WCF. Here's a working example of another (similiar) implementation that I've done:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(CollectionWrapper<IAssociation>))]
public interface IService : 
{
    [OperationContract]
    ICollectionWrapper<IAssociation> FindAssociation(string name, int pageSize, int page);
}

public interface ICollectionWrapper<TModel>
{
    int TotalCount { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<TModel> Items { get; set; }
}

[KnownType(typeof(OrganizationDto))]
[KnownType(typeof(CompanyDto))]
public class CollectionWrapper<TModel> : ICollectionWrapper<TModel>
{
    [DataMember]
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<TModel> Items { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyDto :  IAssociation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class OrganizationDto :  IAssociation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The key here is to use the combination of `KnownType` and `ServiceKnownType`.

So in your case you can do something like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(ActionParameters))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(ActionResult<ISportProgram>))] // Actual implementation of container, but interface of generic.
public interface ISportProgramBl  
{
    [OperationContract]
    IActionResult<ISportProgram> Get(IActionParameters parameters);
}

[KnownType(typeof(SportProgram))] // Actual implementation here.
public class ActionResult<T>
{
    // Other stuff here
    T FooModel { get; set; }
}
```

This will work if you have a shared contract (access to the actual service interface) and consume the contract with `ChannelFactory<ISportProgramBl>`. I do not know if it works with a service-reference.

However, there seems to be some issues with the implementation as mentioned here:

[WCF With a interface and a generic model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35338236/wcf-with-a-interface-and-a-generic-model)

And another similiar question asked and answered here:

[Generic return types with interface type params in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672183/generic-return-types-with-interface-type-params-in-wcf)

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying interfaces in the objects and not concrete types?

```
PPS.Core.DomainModel.Support.Action.ActionListResult<IList<PPS.Core.DomainModel.SportProgram.ISportProgram>>
```

Edit:

What I'm saying is that are all the concrete types that you are passing in the generics (including in sub object via interfaces) being passed in the Known Types  list. We've had serialasation issues where all the types were not known.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a IList of T. It maybe that the system has problems finding out what T is.

Not sure if it is ok to return an interface rather than a type.