# WCF With a interface and a generic model

Tags: c#, wcf, generics, interface

There's a lot of questions on SO regarding interfaces and generics in WCF, but I'm unable to find one that points to the same problem as I have.

I have a service with a contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(CollectionWrapper<IAssociation>))]
public interface IService : 
{
    [OperationContract]
    ICollectionWrapper<IAssociation> FindAssociation(string name, int pageSize, int page);
}

public interface ICollectionWrapper<TModel>
{
    int TotalCount { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<TModel> Items { get; set; }
}

[KnownType(typeof(OrganizationDto))]
[KnownType(typeof(CompanyDto))]
public class CollectionWrapper<TModel> : ICollectionWrapper<TModel>
{
    [DataMember]
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<TModel> Items { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyDto :  IAssociation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class OrganizationDto :  IAssociation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

It's consumed with a `ChannelFactory<IService>` and the code above works great. But now I want to add another method to the service, which also returns `ICollectionWrapper<T>`.

```
[OperationContract]
ICollectionWrapper<ICustomer> Search(ISearchQuery searchQuery);
```

So I register it as I did with the other:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(CollectionWrapper<IAssociation>))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(CollectionWrapper<ICustomer>))] // This line creates the error.
public interface IService : 
{
    [OperationContract]
    ICollectionWrapper<IAssociation> FindAssociation(string name, int pageSize, int page);

    [OperationContract] // New method.
    ICollectionWrapper<ICustomer> Search(ISearchQuery searchQuery);
}

[KnownType(typeof(OrganizationDto))]
[KnownType(typeof(CompanyDto))]
[KnownType(typeof(CustomerDto))] // New model.
public class CollectionWrapper<TModel> : ICollectionWrapper<TModel>
{
    [DataMember]
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<TModel> Items { get; set; }
}
```

And as soon as I have two `ServiceKnownTypes` with `CollectionWrapper` the service fails with the following error:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a receive.

And the inner exception:

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

I can toggle between these two lines of code (remove one, and add the other):

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(CollectionWrapper<ICustomer>))]

[ServiceKnownType(typeof(CollectionWrapper<IAssociation>))]
```

Then each of the methods work, **but never at the same time**. Any idea how to get it to work? I do not want to use concrete classes.

This is what I've tried (and failed):

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(CollectionWrapper<object>))]

[ServiceKnownType(typeof(CollectionWrapper<>))]
```

I also tried to assign a common interface to both IAssociation and ICustomer, but it didn't work either.

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(CollectionWrapper<ISomething>))]
```

It works great for `IEnumerable<T>` and `IList<T>` but not with my `ICollectionWrapper<T>`

**EDIT:**

`ICustomer` and `IAssociation` (and their implementations) have nothing in common. They do not inherit anything from eachother, nor do they have any other common dependencies.

Comment: Perhaps the **inner exception** will give you a better clue: _Type WcfService1.CollectionWrapper`1[WcfService1.ICustomer]' cannot be added to list of known types since another type WcfService1.CollectionWrapper`1[WcfService1.IAssociation]' with the same data contract name 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService1:CollectionWrapperOfanyType' is already present. If there are different collections of a particular type - for example, List&lt;Test&gt; and Test[], they cannot both be added as known types.  Consider specifying only one of these types for addition to the known types list._

Comment: One possible solution is to create, for instance, `public class CustomerCollection : ICollectionWrapper<ICustomer>` and
`public class AssociationCollection : ICollectionWrapper<IAssociation>`.

Comment: @jstreet - Thank you for your suggestions. I've edited my question and added the inner exception. It's a different one than the one you mentioned. Your other suggestion will probably work, but requires more models that does the same thing, which I would like to avoid. But it's a good last resort.

Comment: Well, that inner exception you posted doesn't explain much either... perhaps you have other issues besides the type conflict then. My proposed solution does in fact work. But i think the real solution here is that you need to get clear about your class/interface hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

```
[OperationContract]
ICollectionWrapper<ICustomer> Search(ISearchQuery searchQuery);
```

How does the service know what known types exist for the ISearchQuery parameter?

I think you need to add `[KnownType(typeof(SearchQuery))]` (or whatever your ISearchQuery implementation is called) to your service definition.

Comment: You're absolutely right. But in this case I've tried this by changing ISearchQuery to a string. So, even if this is also an issue, it's not what's causing the error. Besides, the method itself works as long as I remove the other ServiceKnownType.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research I was unable to find a good solution, but I figure I would post the solution I ended up with (even if it didn't solve it the way I wanted)

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(CompanyDto>))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(CompanyDto>))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(CustomerDto))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(OrganizationDto))]
public interface IService : 
{
    [OperationContract] // Concrete type
    CollectionWrapper<IAssociation> FindAssociation(string name, int pageSize, int page);

    [OperationContract] // Concrete type
    CollectionWrapper<ICustomer> Search(ISearchQuery searchQuery);
}
```

It was simply solved by using the concrete class instead of the interface. It's not what I really wanted, but for now it solved my issue.

Possible duplicate here:

[Generic return types with interface type params in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672183/generic-return-types-with-interface-type-params-in-wcf)

Comment: I figure I don't mark it as asnwer since it doesn't really answer my original question (to use generic without concrete classes). I hope that there's a better answer out there...