# Can the return type be base class of a service method?

Tags: java, web-services, service, soa

I've pretty much good experience with [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) (and C#). But my project requires me to write my service in Java (I've no experience in Java). I want to write a service method like this:

```
//Java code!
List<BaseEntity> filter(String dbName, String tableName, String where);
```

From the signature, it looks almost clear that this method is supposed to return a *filtered* list of entities (i.e rows) from the table called `tableName` of `dbName` database and `where` is the condition to filter the rows. The assumption here is that all the classes which represent tables in DB derived from `BaseEntity` base class so that list of any table can be returned from `filter` method.

My question is,

- What framework(s) in Java lets me write this kind of service method?
- In particular, can the return type be bass class so that any derived class objects can be returned?

I know this is possible in WCF using [ServiceKnownTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx) (or [KnownTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx)):

```
//C# code
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(User))]     //User is derived from BaseEntity
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Vendor))]   //Vendor is derived from BaseEntity
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Customer))] //Customer is derived from BaseEntity
List<BaseEntity> Filter(string dbName, string tableName, string where);
```

Now this method can return entities of types : `User`,`Vendor` and `Customer` but *not* any other class which is not listed above the method.

I'm wondering if that is possible in any Java framework also (possibly using different syntax/approach). If there is any solution, I also would like to know if it is WSDL-compatible (because the clients could be written in any language, C++, Python or Java, so I assume the solution needs to be WSDL-compatible).

Comment: Yes, from java 1.5 you can return base class object from any service method. they are called as covariant returns. So no problem in this

Comment: @ankit: Sorry, it is not *any* method. It is a *service* method. So being it a service, there might be some restrictions.

Comment: by service method do you mean web service, or you are talking about DAL(Data Access Layer). but as per my knowledge there is no problem in both the cases, anyways we can wait for some good answers thats why I preferred commenting rather than answering :)

Comment: @ankit: By service, I meant a process which will run on a remote machine, and the clients will make request to it through `http` (or any other protocol). That sounds like a web-service, probably?

Comment: yes this web service only. In my previous project I had created a soap web service which was returning base class, as there were lot of derived classes which my method could return. So I guess you can go ahead without any problem

Comment: Is [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450807/java-generics-how-do-i-make-the-method-return-type-generic) helpful in anyway?

Comment: I think you can`t, maybe this thread will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376495/wcf-interfaces-generics-and-serviceknowntype

Comment: @jmhostalet: That thread is about WCF which is .NET. I'm looking for Java solution. (BTW, it is possible in .NET)